# The time-derivative of the Hamiltonian for a 1D harmonic potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory

I do not understand how to take the time derivative of the following Hamiltonian  $\hat{H}(t) = \frac{\hat{p}^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2}m\omega^2(\hat{x}-a(t))^2$, where $a(t) = v_0t$. For instance how does $\hat{p}$ change when taking the time derivative of it? And the same for $\hat{x}$.

Comment: $\hat x$ and $\hat p$ are time-independent in this (Schrödinger) picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Schrödinger picture (which seems like what you're working with), $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ don't have any time dependence.  This means that the only time dependence of $\hat{H}$ comes from the explicit $t$-dependence in the form that you've written, so
$$
\frac{d\hat{H}}{dt} = \frac{\partial\hat{H}}{\partial t} = - m \dot{a}(t) \omega^2 (\hat{x} - a(t)).
$$

Comment: So if there is nothing else stated, one can assume that we are always in the Schrödinger picture?

Comment: The Schrödinger and Heisenberg pictures always agree about observable quantities; they're just different ways of thinking about the situation.  I'd say that the "default" way is usually the Schrödinger picture, but it doesn't really matter.  In the Heisenberg picture, you actually have $d\hat{H}/dt = \partial\hat{H}/\partial t$ too because the term that you pick up in the time dependence of an operator $\hat{O}$ is proportional to $[\hat{O}, \hat{H}]$, and $\hat{H}$ commutes with itself.  But you don't need this to answer your question: you are talking about the Schrödinger picture.